# WildFly 10 Hibernate 5 Spring 4.2 and JTA stack throws ResourceException

Tags: spring, hibernate, wildfly, jta, hibernate-5.x

I have EAR with simple non-JPA Hibernate based domain and dao submodules and web submodule. I want to use JTA and container managed transactions. When deploying on WildFly 9 (using Hibernate4) everything works fine. I migrated the app to WildFly 10 (using Hibernate5) but after several clicks in browser an exception is thrown:

**EDIT:** added full stacktrace:

```
08:34:29,733 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-22) UT005023: Exception handling request to /wildfly-hibernate5-error/waterNow.do: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:778)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:90)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:240)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:184)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:120)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:85)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3893)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:488)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:453)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:196)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:258)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:134)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1071)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:164)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2627)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:955)
at org.jboss.spring.examples.primrose.dao.FlowerDaoImpl.find(FlowerDaoImpl.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.find(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.spring.examples.primrose.springmvc.FlowerController.waterNow(FlowerController.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:442)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:430)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:66)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:382)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
... 76 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:646)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:430)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:737)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
... 80 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:569)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getTransactionNewConnection(AbstractPool.java:711)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:608)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:579)
... 83 more
```

I created simple reproducer on github, see https://github.com/trepel/primrose-hibernate-simple

Please, if you can have an idea what could go wrong, please let me know.

**EDIT:** I have further simplified the reproducer, now it is just simple Spring-based web application (war archive), see https://github.com/trepel/wildfly-hibernate5-error

Thank you very much for your hints.

Comment: I'd suggest you file an issue https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBJCA/. This looks like a bug in either IronJacamar or Hibernate.

Comment: Done, see [JBJCA-1290](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBJCA-1290)

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't think it would get rejected so quickly as it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace? Looks like transactions aren't working properly leading to connection leakage.

Comment: Full stacktrace added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally know, what is wrong, the line

`hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class=jta`

must be added into `hibernate.properties` file

For details see https://developer.jboss.org/message/944678#944678